# Restore the default connection details

Tags: networking

How can I restore the default gateway? I had to make some changes in etc/network/interfaces/ like configure a new interface and new gateway (this is for a homework). I cannot change the informations added in etc/network/interfaces because I would lose my points, but I must have my internet connection fixed. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do so manually from the command line by using:

```
sudo ip route del default
sudo ip route add default via 10.17.17.2 dev wlan0 proto static
```

in which you of course alter the ip to your gateway and wlan0 to the card to use for this connection

Enjoy surfing again! :)

PS. This is a temp solution, after reboot you have to do this again because it runs the rules out of etc.

*editted to first remove the existing default gateway*